# Given a list of ints a, return a new list using recursion which contains all positive elements of a

Tags: java, list, recursion

> Given a list of integers a, return a new list which contains all the positive elements of `a` using recursion. The elements should appear in the result in the same relative order as in `a`. i.e. `[2, 3, -5, 8, -2] ==> [2, 3, 8]`.

```
public static List positives(List a) {
    if (a.isEmpty())
        return List.empty();
    if (a.getHead() > 0)
        return  positives(a.getTail()); 
    else
    return List.cons(0, a);
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? What is your question (requirement != question).

Comment: I am new to recursion and lists and this little problem is confusing me. When I test it, the code returns mixed up results. Would appreciate any help to show me where I am going wrong please. Thank you.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile for me. What is your `List`?

Comment: List is just a class that defines a recursive type called List, and provides
 constructor and getter methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't posted the code of `List` but this is what the algorithm should look like:

- If the list is empty, return an empty list (`List.empty()`).
- If the head element is positive (`a.getHead() > 0`), keep it and return a list of that element and the positive elements of the tail (with `List.cons`).
- If the head element is negative, drop it and just return the list of positive elements from the tail.

In your current code, the first point is correctly done but the two other ones are incorrect: in the case where the head element is positive, you are ignoring it (when you should be doing that if the head element is negative instead).

This should be enough for you to correct the code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Tunaki, I will try that out now!

Answer (score 1):

This looks a lot like LISP.

Instead of

```
return List.cons(0, a);
```

use

```
return List.cons(a.getHead(), positives(a.getTail());
```

Comment: Thank you, used that after changing my code from "if (a.getHead() > 0)" to if (a.getHead() < 0).

Comment: @SteveChalmers and does it work, and do you understand why?

Comment: Yes it works thank you. I think I know how it works but I am new to recursion so not comfortable with it yet. I will write it out on paper to try to understand each step. Thanks again.

Comment: @SteveChalmers if you are using eclipse you can have a breakpoint on each return and inspect the list each time.